# cmake equivalent for CONFIG += qmltypes

Tags: qt, cmake

[This](https://www.qt.io/blog/qml-type-registration-in-qt-5.15) link explains how to register qml component with 5.15. I need to add

```
CONFIG += qmltypes
```

to my .pro file but I'm using cmake and did not find a way to do it.

What could it be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look into the comments in the blog post you linked you can see people asking about how to use new QML type registration approach with `CMake` and the author responds:

```
CMake projects will be supported with Qt6.
```

I suppose you need to go with the old way of registration with CMake, e.g.

```
qmlRegisterType<Person>("People", 1,0, "Person");
```